# ES2015 not working with gulp-browserify and vueify

Tags: node.js, gulp, browserify, vue.js, babeljs

I'm working on a website in node.js and I use vueify which I compile using gulp, but it's not working. I've tried using babelify to handle ES2015, but Gulp still gives me errors when I want to use `import App from './App.vue'` for example

This is my code

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var path = require('path');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var vueify = require('vueify');

gulp.task('build', function() {
return gulp.src(path.join(resDir, 'vue/main.js'))
.pipe(browserify({ transform: ['vueify', 'babelify'], debug: true }))
.pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(destDir, 'javascript')))
});
```

and main.js

```
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.devtools = true

Vue.use(VueResource)

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  components: { App }
})
```

Comment: Can you provide more code? You're referencing browserify and two transforms but I don't see where you are bringing those into your gulp file.

Comment: @jostrander I've now added the transform I forgot. I also added the entry point for vue.